# Hint on solving $ \frac{dx}{dt} = t - tx $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you please give me a hint how to continue solving this differential equation?

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = t - tx $$

Rewriting yields

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} + tx = t $$

Now I can use integrating factor

$$ \mu = e^{\int t dt} = e^{t^2 / 2} $$

So I can multiply whole equation with $ \mu $ and integrate both sides

$$ e^{t^2 / 2} x = \int te^{t^2 / 2}dt$$

To solve integral on r.h.s. I put $u = t$ and $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = e^{t^2 / 2}$, so
$\frac{du}{dt} = 1;\;\;v = \int e^{t^2 / 2} dt$.

Now this second integral leads to substitution, let's put $z=t^2 / 2$, so $ \;\dfrac{dz}{dt} = t $.

That is, $\; dt = \dfrac{dz}{t}.\;$ Putting back to integral yields

$$ \int \frac{e^z}{t}dz $$

But i don't know how to solve this. I only went through examples, where substitution eliminated occurrence of original variable.

Comment: $\int t e^{t^2/2}\,dt = \int e^w\, dw$ (set $w=t^2/2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At an early stage you had reached 
$$e^{t^2/2}x=\int te^{t^2/2}\,dt.$$
The integral on the right yields to the substitution $u=t^2/2$. We get $e^{t^2/2}+C$, and we are finished.

Comment: Thanks, this led to right solution. How to distinguish whether to use substitution or integration by parts?

Comment: It is hard to give general criteria, though here the derivative of $t^2/2$ was sitting in front, not even in disguise. I have noticed in the past that good students sometimes get enthusiastic about integration by parts, and overlook the simpler tools.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $t-tx=t(1-x)$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach and I finished with right solution as well. The reason why I used integrating factor is that this equation was in exercise focused on integrating factors.

Answer (score 5):

Do you see that you can separate the variables?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = t - tx = (1 - x)t$$
$$\dfrac{1}{1 - x}\,dx = t dt$$

Comment: The equation was in exercise focused on integrating factor, so I used it in my calculation. But this led to the right solution too. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, fully. Nice work, and + for your effort!

Comment: @amWhy: ALways good for OPs to have more approaches! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Different approaches means different tastes +)